# Mailgun.js to retrieve message info and status

Tags: mailgun

I'm using [`mailgun.js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun.js?utm_source=recordnotfound.com#install) from `npm`.
How the retrieve message data and info using the `message_id` with `mailgun.js`?

To send a message I do

```js
    mailgun.messages.create(MAILGUN_API_DOMAIN, mailOptions);
```

so to retrieve info I was expecting something like

```js
    mailgun.messages.info(MAILGUN_API_DOMAIN, mg_id);
```

but it's NOT. I can't see anything in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun.js?utm_source=recordnotfound.com#install). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

this is the best I found, using `events`

```js
    mailgun.events.get(MAILGUN_DOMAIN, { 'message-id': mg_id })
```

I get a list of all the events of that message (accepted, delivered, open, clicked...) with details for each event